# Return a list of possible result from another column in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a search function to search column A2:A10. When I type in a value in cell B1, let say's "AG", and then it will return a 4 possible result in list.

Is that possible? Many thanks.[image]

Comment: It would be a  lot easier to accomplish that if you would search from the side bar then you could use html elements to receive the suggestions.  Also provide the data in the image in a table would make it easier for us to work with your data.

Comment: Here's a script you may wish to start with: `function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    e.source.toast("gate1")
    const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().filter(v => v.indexOf(e.value) == 0);
    e.range.clearContent();
    e.range.clearDataValidations();
    let r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(vs).build();
    e.range.setDataValidation(r);
  }
}` I don't want to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work as you type but when you complete the cell and hit enter or tab it will give the items matching your search string in cell B1.

[image]

Reference

- [Query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)